# C getchar() and putchar()

Tags: c, getchar, putchar

Going through K&R, I'm trying to get my head around C.
I want to write a program that prints on the screen the user's previous line, unless the character was "a".

```
int main(){

int c;

while((c=getchar())!=EOF){

     if(c!='a')
            putchar(c);
}
return 0;
}
```

Yes, the program isn't much. But it won't work as intended. Do I need to use the ASCII value of the character "a", because the above code just prints all the letters regardless of being a or not.

Comment: I just ran the code and it works fine for me?

Comment: So it doesnt print the character a when a is typed?

Comment: correct the output I receive is print letter the entered letter for all but the letter a, that was with a direct copy and paste of your code. It does print out the carriage return, if you enter a string of letters **lalala** it will output **lll** as using a while loop and getchar it will keep looping through input buffer till empty. That is also why you see carriage return

Comment: ah. I made a really stupid mistake. It works fine. Write your reply as an answer and I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: I think you are confusing the terminal echoing your input and what your program is outputting.  Try "echo lalala | ./test > result" and then "cat result".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code should work as specified, but what you will find is that using `getchar` with the while loop will print a carriage return when a is entered. This is because in the current implementation `getchar` will keep reading the input buffer till it is empty, if you wanted to stop this happening you could flush it in the if statement.

Entering a string of text at the moment will print the string removing any *a*s

Comment: Sorry, but no.  [getchar](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getchar.html) returns an int; [putchar](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/putchar.html) takes an int.